# print html table to excel using angular 7

Tags: excel, html-table, angular7, xlsx

I need to export my table in excel using angular 7. Almost I tried with packages like xlsx,exceljs etc where I can achieve till table format like normal way is working fine. But in case of like this,

```
<table class="darkTable" id="tblData" table border="1">
<tr><th>10.70.96.202</th>
<td>

    <table class="darkTable" id="tblData" table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>header 4</th></tr><tr><td>data 1</td><td>data2</td><td>data 3</td>
      <td><ul style="list-style: none;"><li>
        <table class="darkTable" id="tblData" table border="1"><tr>
          <th>Name</th><td>network data</td>
      </tr><tr><th>Recv</th><td>Application</td></tr></table>
    </li></ul></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

[image]

In excel its coming like this,
[image]

Instead of comes within cell of td,its taking seperate row
But I want show exact view as in html can anyone suggest good solution for my issue.

Thanks in advance,